# How to get the missing rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

Example schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01c068/2
For any insertion `author.created_at` is same as `books.created_at` and `author.previous_created_at` is same as second highest created date in books table.
What is the best way to find out the missing record in latest insertion?
The expected result is the rows having `books.id = 4`

Answer (score 0):

You question is not completely clear to me, but I think the code below is what you're looking for. Or at least that it will help.

I would like to note however, that the table 'author' does not contain any data about authors. It also cannot differentiate between different authors. So you might want to redesign some elements of your project.

Is this what you are looking for? And if not, could you give a little more explanation and some examples?

```
select B.id as bookID
, B.author_id
, B.created_at
, sub.previous_created_at 
from books as B
left join (
            select id
            , author_id
            , created_at as previous_created_at 
            from books 
            ) as sub
          on sub.id + 1 = B.id
          and sub.author_id = B.author_id
```

This query returns all books with its author and created_at, and in the final column the  created_at of the previous book by the same author.